# Configuring Apache with Ruby on rails on Windows

Tags: ruby, apache

I have installed [Rubyinstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/) as i intend to work with Ruby on Rails on Windows. I have used Apache HTTP in several web projects previously and i am very familiar with it.
Is there any tutorial that i should follow to configure it properly with Ruby? At the moment i have found this [guide](http://hivelogic.com/articles/a-do-it-yourself-guide-to-installing-ruby-rails-and-fastcgi/), but it's for MacOS ONLY and i think that i would have got some problems.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/start/

I've used it,  and actually had windows based Ruby on Rails IN PRODUCTION!